# How to keep a shell alive after it gets started from inside a program?

Tags: shell, python, pipe, c

I was not sure where to ask this question, since it is a mix of both programming and Linux, but hopefully this is the right place. I have written a simple program, which I'm buffer overflowing. I have completed every single step in my exploit, but one. When I run my shell code, `/bin/bash` gets executed and then closes immediately since it doesn't have an input. I call my program with one argument like this `./vuln arg` `arg` having the shell code.
As I understand it, the shell needs some input, but when my vulnerable program is done, it closes the pipe, which should receive standard input, and thus also closes my shell. I get the following message

```
/bin/sh: line 1: warning: command substitution: ignored null byte in input
```

Below my code in C if that helps:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv){
    char buffer[100];
    strcpy(buffer, argv[1]);

    return 0;
}
```

And the command I use to open a shell:

```
./vuln $(python -c "import sys; sys.stdout.buffer.write(b'\x90'*60 + b'\x31\xc0\x50\x68\x2f\x2f\x73\x68\x68\x2f\x62\x69\x6e\x89\xe3\x89\xc1\x89\xc2\xb0\x0b\xcd\x80\x31\xc0\x40\xcd\x80' + b'\x40\xd6\xff\xff'*6)")
```

I have already tried:

```
./vuln $(python -c "import sys; sys.stdout.buffer.write(b'\x90'*60 + b'\x31\xc0\x50\x68\x2f\x2f\x73\x68\x68\x2f\x62\x69\x6e\x89\xe3\x89\xc1\x89\xc2\xb0\x0b\xcd\x80\x31\xc0\x40\xcd\x80' + b'\x40\xd6\xff\xff'*6)") | cat
```

or even with `;` instead of `|`, and some other different variants, but none has worked
This is the error I get when I just run `./vuln my_payload`

```
[Detaching after fork from child process 4010]
bash: warning: command substitution: ignored null byte in input
[Detaching after fork from child process 4011]
```

Comment: Unless you do something to change it, the shell you start from `vuln` should have its stdin connected to the terminal the same as its parent. Running an additional `cat` won't change that. It might help to know what your code actually does. I don't know about anyone else, but I'm not going to decode the hexdump.

Comment: @ilkkachu if you are referring to my shell code, i took it from here: http://shell-storm.org/shellcode/files/shellcode-811.html. it should do the following: ```execve("/bin/sh")```. when i just run ```vuln``` without anything else, other than my script, i get the error i edited in my question

Comment: @r3, hmm. Do you know the shell does get executed to begin with? Or are you just assuming it does? Run it with strace and see the system calls it makes? How are you determining and setting the address to return to? How do you know where the stack is so that you can return to it?

Comment: @ilkkachu i'm assuming it gets executed, since i get the following message on ```gdb``` ```process 15377 is executing new program: /usr/bin/bash```. on how i'm performing a buffer overflow, i'm following the steps shown in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1S0aBV-Waeo. i'm returning to the middle of the NOPs i have inserted

Comment: @ilkkachu i'm also following this video:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HSlhY4Uy8SA, which explains a similar problem i have, but there you are asked for your input with ```gets```, and in my case i want to pass it as an argument, when i first execute my program. it's pretty similar to my problem, but not quite the same

Comment: The command line isn't suited for passing raw bytes, as you saw from the error. Try passing the stream of bytes through a [FIFO](https://www.mankier.com/1/mkfifo) (named pipe), which you can read or write in binary mode.

Comment: @Vilinkameni, except that there are no NULs in the output of that Python command, so the command line is absolutely fine for that. (There can't really be any NULs in the payload anyway since `strcpy()` also stops when seeing one.)

Comment: @r3, in any case, that also means that it's a bit unclear as to what you did to get that "ignored null byte in input" error

Comment: @ilkkachu Yes, that's why I recommended named pipes, which can be read in binary mode (*replacing* the `strcpy`; btw - off topic - that function is dangerous and `strlcpy` should be used instead, checking overflow), including NUL bytes.

Comment: I was thinking about something like [`read`(3p)](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pread.html), which takes number of bytes to read as a parameter and doesn't deal with NUL-terminated arrays (strings), unlike the `str*` family of functions.

Comment: @Vilinkameni, there's nothing inherently dangerous in `strcpy` provided it's used properly. And if used improperly, `strlcpy` is just as dangerous. And if the payload contained NULs, `strlcpy` wouldn't copy them any better than `strcpy` does. But it doesn't, so the command line is fine, `strcpy` is fine, and pipes or whatever aren't needed.

Comment: @Vilinkameni my goal is to actually exploit the weakness of ```strcpy```. I want to exploit my code, and not make it safer.

Comment: @ilkkachu i don't know why i get "ignored null byted in input", or why i don't get a new shell. the only thing i do is run my script, that i have also provided in the question above. but i also have to say, that i'm not 100% sure what the shellcode does, since i'm not that familiar with assembly, i only took it from the website, but it does say "process 15377 is executing new program: /usr/bin/bash".

Comment: @r3k0j, the code is pretty clear when you see it disassembled (like [here](http://shell-storm.org/shellcode/files/shellcode-811.html)). It pushes the string `/bin//sh` into the stack in two parts, sets up the registers containing the args to the system call and makes the call with INT 0x80. (yes, there's a double slash there, regardless of what the video says, it's likely to pad to 8 bytes.) I think it's just `execve("/bin//sh", NULL, NULL)`

Comment: I think the last part of the binary data (the `\x40\xd6\xff\xff`) is supposed to be the return address, but I suppose that only works on a 32-bit system with no randomization for the stack location... Meaning I can't really get it to work myself.

Comment: Ho hum. I started to wonder if that error can come from something in the startup files that might be read by the shell that gets started. What do you get if you change it to run `/bin/ls` instead? (Change the `\x2f\x2f\x73\x68` part to `\x2f\x2f\x6c\x73`). Or `/bin/cat`? (`\x2f\x63\x61\x74`)

Comment: @ilkkachu it works with ```/bin/ls``` and also with ```/bin/cat```. and you were correct about the last part being the return address, and that the program is compiled as a 32-bit with no randomization for the stack location. my program is compiled with all defense mechanisms removed

Comment: @ilkkachu Like I said, the topic of "`strlcpy` vs `strcpy`" is off topic, I mentioned it purely because I saw `strcpy`, used like in the majority of cases ("improperly", that is without checking bounds). On the subject, one can consult https://www.openbsd.org/papers/strlcpy-paper.pdf and https://marc.info/?l=openbsd-tech&m=138733933417096&w=2. Back to the topic: my idea was to not use any `str*` functions at all, if the data potentially contains NUL bytes. However, I see that was not the idea @r3k0j had in mind.